# Install4j uninstaller running in console/CLI mode by default

Tags: java, installation, uninstallation, install4j

We have developed installer application for Cent OS 7.5, our installer is running in GUI mode without any issue but uninstaller for same is running in console/CLI mode, we have set default execution mode to GUI still the issue persist.

Install4j Version : 9.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uninstaller has its own "Default execution mode" property in the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step.

Comment: Hi Ingo Kegel both installer and uninstaller has default execution mode GUI mode, still it is running in CLI mode

Comment: The only reason why the uninstaller would fall back to console mode is when it is running with a headless JRE or access to the X-server is not possible.

Comment: How can we check whether it is running with headless JRE or whether access to X-server is not possible is there is any way where we can confirm the same as our Installer with same config on same machine is able to run in GUI mode

Comment: You can use ps to check what JRE is being used by displaying the command line

Comment: We have bundled pre created JRE which getting used for Installer but for uninstaller it is using the machine specific JRE which is 1.8.0_242, we have bundled using media file options JRE bundles -> bundle pre created JRE

Comment: OK, that explains the problem, the machine-specific JRE is likely a headless JRE. The question is now why the uninstaller does not find the bundled JRE.  You could add echo outputs to the uninstaller start script in the parts of the scripts where JREs are tested to find out more. Is the "jre" folder in teh installation directory still present when the uninstaller runs?

Comment: Thanks Ingo Kegel. JRE folder was getting deleted after installation which caused this issue.

Comment: Can you help us with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72489650/install4j-rollback-not-initiated-on-centos-machine-on-closing-the-terminal-or-ki