# Install4j rollback not initiated on CentOS machine on closing the terminal or killing the process

Tags: install4j

We have developed Installer for CentOS 7.5, we are running Installer on CentOS when Installation action is started where we copy files and folder and then actual shell scripts of Installation, during this if we close terminal window then sh process is getting killed but no rollback is imitated which is configured by Install4j failed/failure event.

We want to perform rollback when such process kill/terminal close scenario is observed.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be possible to perform a rollback if the process is killed. Rollbacks are performed when the user enters CTRL-C on the command line or cancels the GUI wizard.